# I don't like the synopsis of the results in the 2022 Survey

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, survey, survey-2022

Can we see the original form of the survey questions? For example, the very first question in the Developer Profile, ["Learning How to Code"](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#section-learning-to-code-learning-how-to-code), it made it seem like you only learn from one source (when viewing the data by age):

[image: Results of the "Learning how to code" section of the survey, broken down by age, with each age group expressed as a per-category breakdown adding up to 100%]

I could have sworn that the question stated "check all that apply".  Hence, it makes absolutely no sense, from a statistical/ survey perspective, to try to show them as "buckets" by age:
[2022 Survey Learning How to Code by Age](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#section-learning-to-code-learning-how-to-code) (you will have to click the button "by age" to see my point).

If the survey did NOT say "check all that apply", it does not make any sense to pigeon hole how one learns to ONE learning mechanism? So either the survey question was done poorly, or the tabulated results were done poorly, hence my request for a link to a list of all the original questions (especially check one vs. check all that apply).

Comment: The raw (anonymized) data and sheet of the original questions is released at a later date for those who would like to analyze on their own.

Comment: I just saw the little note that stated "check all that apply".  Hence, the How to Code by Age REPORT makes no sense.  If "Check All That Apply" is in a survey on delicious ice cream flavors between "Vanilla" and "Chocolate", how would the data be presented if 50% said Vanilla and 50% said Chocolate, vs 60% said Vanilla and 60% said chocolate, vs. 100% said Vanilla and 100% said Chocolate?

Comment: @animuson:  For the sake of trust and faith in the process, could that be expedited?  It's a bad look to imply that these were the values and analysis you extrapolated from this set of data, when those who took the survey may have had differing expectations or don't believe that the questions they were asked align with the analysis being proclaimed.

Comment: @Makoto There really is no way to expedite it, no. It takes as long as it takes. But it appears that the small text below the analysis _is_ the full and original question, with whether it is a multi-select, so I suppose the request for all the questions is already complete. They are available directly in the survey results.

Comment: There was no "dreaded" option, for example, and yet again, somehow that's a data point again this year.

Comment: @KevinB There _was_ ample opportunity for respondents to weigh in on how little they liked something, which is not that much of a step from inferring "dreaded", FWIW.

Comment: @TylerH the question was... What do you use now, and do you *want* to use it next year, neither has anything to do with what we like

Comment: @KevinB Oh I thought there was one like in the past that asked on a sliding scale how much you liked stuff. All the years are bleeding together on me.

Comment: Oh, the actual question is listed in the results: "Which development environments did you use regularly over the past year, and which do you want to work with over the next year? Please check all that apply."

Comment: I find it disingenuous to say the most loved X isn't the one that received the most "Wants"

Comment: While the visualization isn't the best, I don't see that it is necessarily wrong. Once one groups-by age, the percent for each response is shown. There's nothing here that says that a single person did not contribute to multiple learning styles. If only five people age 18-24 responded, and all five people checked all the boxes, then each box would show 11.111% (there are 9 categories).
Either way, the visualization should make it clear if the percent is the percentage of person responses, or the distribution of learning styles within each age group. Mathematically, its got to be the latter.

Comment: The only goal here was to come up with a visualization that resembled a rainbow. So disappointing y'all focus on statistical relevance ...

Comment: Lesson learnt should be: always think about units of numbers. The x axis simply goes from 0 to 100% but % of what? If it would be customary to write the unit next to an axis, maybe the mistake would have been detected earlier, because the units as it is would have been "total number of selected options" but that's probably not a unit that is very meaningful, unless the average number of selected options is constant over age.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First– (as you discovered) all result panes in the released summary of results include the original question noted below the results view, in the bottom left corner:

[image: Results of the "learning to code" section of the survey, divided out by age, with arrows drawn to indicate that the original question text is noted in the bottom left corner of the area]

> How did you learn to code? Select all that apply.

Second, I completely agree that on this particular question the distribution doesn't make sense, at least not as currently rendered.

If we compare the age view to the "all respondents" view:

[image: Results of the "learning to code" section of the survey, all respondents]

The "all respondents" layout makes total sense– the bars don't total to 100%, because the responses included in one bar aren't mutually exclusive from another.

In the age view, however, the bars *do* total to 100, which I can't figure out how to rectify with the question wording. I have a hunch that this is just an improper rendering of the data, rather than an improper *understanding* of that data, but the point remains that the percentages are either completely wrong or just useful for comparison, which is still misleading. These bars should not total to 100%.

So, to your point, unless we're both misunderstanding something, **either the data was interpreted wrong, or the rendering of it is wrong**, and something about the age view should be updated to rectify it.

Comment: I'm wondering how it could be rendered differently, other a set of layouts similar to "all respondents" but where each one is based on age.

Comment: @franji1 "I'm wondering how it could be rendered differently,..." Bars of different length, where the length is normalized to the number of participants answering the question in each category, instead of the number of all checked answers.

Comment: I have a theory: of everyone that selected an age breakdown, how many selected any of the options. Except that that is still wrong. If it was the opposite (age breakdown per option), it should also include those that selected none.

Answer (score 19):

Thank you for flagging this!! The chart was rendered incorrectly as some suggested. It was rendered as a **stacked bar** when it should have been a **clustered bar**.

It will now correctly show; *The percent of respondents within each age bin that used each resource.* Also, note that we order the choices by the order set in **All Respondents** to stay consistent across each age bin.

[image]

Plus we get to keep the rainbow aesthetic!

Comment: YES!  Maintaining the category order (=> maintain color order) in the *By Age* graphs let you more easily compare/contrast categories *By Age*.